# MS SQL Aggregate View

Tags: sql-server

I have a very basic table within an MS SQL DB.

| Product | Amount | Storage Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | A |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 2 | 20 | B |
| 2 | 30 | C |
| 3 | 10 | D |

Essentially, I would like a view that ignores the location of the products, but just aggregates the total `Amount` for each product.

So in this instance, I'd end up with the below. What is the best way to achieve this? A view? I'm very new to SQL and muddling through at the moment!

```
1 --> 44
2 --> 50
3 --> 10
```

Comment: Is this not a straight grouping `SELECT Product, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM YourTable GROUP BY Product`

Comment: Will that update in real time as the the table that contains this data gets populated with additional products?

Comment: Yes, views don't store any data, they just show what is currently in the table when you query them. You don't have to use a view, you can just have a direct query

Comment: The view will be pulled through into a web app directly.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You don't need a view, you can query using a direct SQL `SELECT` query. A view is just a convenient way to store such a query.

Comment: What are the researches you did before writing this post on SO?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CharlieFace in the comments;

```
SELECT Product, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM YourTable GROUP BY Product
```